# C# method DateTime.TryParse() behaves differently on same machine in BizTalk versus Console app

Tags: c#, datetime, biztalk, regional-settings, biztalk-2016

Consider the following lines of code:

```
DateTime d;
DateTime.TryParse("16-10-2020", out d);
```

When run inside a console app the date time 16-10-2020 00:00:00 is returned. Culture nl-NL is used, as defined in my windows regional settings. However, when run inside a Biztalk 2016 pipeline component on a 64 bit hostinstance, 16-10-2020 is not a valid date. Upon inspection it appears culture en-US is used to parse the date string. I did not explicitly specify any culture to be used in my code, therefore expecting nl-NL to be used by BizTalk as well.

Both scenario's are running on identical .NET Framework version on the same machine. What explains the difference in behavior?

I cannot find any specific culture configuration in my BizTalk server config. Could it be that BizTalk stored culture info somewhere I am unaware of during installation, but failed to update when regional settings changed? Just guessing. Anybody?

Comment: I don't know biztalk but if you want a specific culture, why don't you use explicitly anyway? You could also be more specific and use `TryParseExact()` if the format is fixed.

Comment: See following to set culture in svc file : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056424/add-basichttpbinding-to-biztalk-esb-toolkit-wcf-service-esb-itineraryservices-w

Comment: I'm guessing BizTalk is running under another account that has different regional settings. Perhaps [this site](https://randypaulo.com/2012/09/03/biztalk-how-to-fix-regional-settings-problem-decimal-number-formatting) can help with that. In any case I agree with 41686d6564 you should probably set the format explicitly.

Comment: Maybe problem are different regional settings.
Are you try to use [InvariantCulture]? [InvariantCulture]:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Indeed the BTS service is running under a service account with different regional settings. Ruud thanks for the solution!

Comment: @Ruud You should post that as the answer

Answer (score 0):

The BizTalk service account had different regional settings than my user, which explained the difference in behavior.

Better use TryParse exact if the format is known upfront.